# Return statement not providing correct amount of filtered courses in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input, return

## Problem

I'm making a map where the pins that are displayed changed based on what option has been selected in a set of dropdown menus.

I've gotten to a point where I can click the option for Missouri, Illinois and an 18-hole course and the map will re-create itself with the new pins. However, when I select the option for `9-hole courses` **the filtered array shows one value when there are about 25 courses in this category.**

#### Update #1

Changed the index.html to reflect the correct `select option`

## Objective

- Click on an option from one of the dropdown menus and then show only pins
  pertaining to those values on the map
- Have a user be able to make a selection from the `state` dropdown, which contains the options Missouri and Illinois **AND** `holes` which contains 9-hole and 18-hole and show ie. *A 9-hole course in Missouri*

### scripts.js

```
<script>


    // This provides an array of all the courses
    var locations = [
        {% for content in COPY.courses %}
        {
            "name": "{{ content.name }}",
            "lat": "{{ content.lat }}",
            "lng": "{{ content.lng }}",
            "state": "{{ content.state }}",
            "holes": "{{ content.holes }}"
        },
        {% endfor %}
    ];

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("select").change(function(){

            var courseValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            console.log(courseValue);

            locations_filtered = locations.filter(function(el) {
                if (courseValue === "MO" || courseValue === "IL") {
                    return el.state == courseValue;
                } else if (courseValue === "9" || courseValue === "18") {
                    return el.holes == courseValue;
                }
            })

            $("#map").empty();
            makeMap(locations_filtered);
        });
    });

    function initMap() {
        makeMap(locations);
    }

    function makeMap(locations) {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.6270, -90.1994),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i].name);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

        }
    }
</script>
```

### The data structure looks like this for each of the roughly 100 courses

```
{
    "name": "Buffalo Ridge",
    "lat": "36.575508",
    "lng": "-93.190777",
    "state": "MO",
    "holes": "18"
},
```

### index.html

```
<div class="header__filter filter--home">
            <label>Filter By State</label>

            <select>
                <option value="default" disabled="disabled">Pick an option</option>
                <option value="All">All states</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="header__filter filter--home">
            <label>Filter By Holes</label>

            <select>
                <option value="default" disabled="disabled">Pick an option</option>
                <option value="All">All holes</option>
                <option value="9">9-hole course</option>
                <option value="18">18-hole course</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

- Create two variables one for the `stateValue` and the other for the `holeValue`
- Add classes to your select, in this case `select_state` and `select_hole`
- You wanted to create a filtered array from the array of all
  locations. We are just going to call this `firstfilter`.
- You then want to filter that array again, we'll call that
  `secondFilter`
- You'll want to change your variable for courseValue to `stateValue`
  in the `firstFilter` and `holeValue` in your `secondFilter`
- The reason that `=== "9"` was not working is because it doesn't match in value and type as you were comparing a string to a number. Use `parseInt` in this case.
- Pass your `secondFilter` to makeMap

### scripts.js

```
<script>


    // This provides an array of all the courses
    var locations = [
        {% for content in COPY.courses %}
        {
            "name": "{{ content.name }}",
            "lat": "{{ content.lat }}",
            "lng": "{{ content.lng }}",
            "state": "{{ content.state }}",
            "holes": "{{ content.holes }}"
        },
        {% endfor %}
    ];

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("select").change(function(){

            var stateValue = $(".select_state:visible").find(":selected").val();
            var holeValue = $(".select_hole:visible").find(":selected").val();

            var firstFilter = locations.filter(function(el) {
                if (stateValue === "MO" || stateValue == "IL") {
                    return el.state === stateValue;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            var secondFilter = firstFilter.filter(function(el) {
                if (holeValue === "9" || holeValue == "18") {
                    return parseInt(el.holes) === parseInt(holeValue);
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            })

            console.log(firstFilter);
            console.log(secondFilter);

            $("#map").empty();
            makeMap(secondFilter);
        });
    });

    function initMap() {
        makeMap(locations);
    }

    function makeMap(locations) {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.6270, -90.1994),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i].name);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

        }
    }
</script>
```